# Laravel get previous record in db via hasOne relationship along with first record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got a model called `Beam` and a model called `BeamData`. My Beams in my database use a uuid for the id column, and each record in my `BeamData` model has a `beam_id` column.

When I query a single `Beam`, I fetch the associated `BeamData` by the `beam_id` column, it should fetch the newest data linked to that beam, thus why I have the `orderBy.

I now need to fetch two beam data records for a single Beam, whereby I fetch the newest one, and the previous record in the DB, or, the two newest records for that model.

I'm not sure how to achieve this in my existing `hasOne` relationship, there won't always be two `BeamData` records, by default there will be none.

How can I modify my relationship to achieve said deliverables?

```php
/**
 * The relationships that should always be loaded.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $with = ['beam_data'];

/**
 * Get the phone associated with the user.
 */
public function beam_data()
{
    // TODO: I need the newest, and second newest record if there is one, ordered by newest to oldest
    return $this->hasOne(BeamData::class, 'beam_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: use hasMany relation

Comment: I only need 2 results, would this work: `$this->hasMany(BeamData::class, 'beam_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(2);`

Comment: yes this should work

Comment: it should be $this->hasMany(BeamData::class, 'beam_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(2)